# Recipient list Router with selector expression

Tags: spring, spring-integration, router

I am getting the string messages in a Queue. I am consuming it and doing further processing using the below channel `processMessage`.

Now I have a requirement where I need to send this messages to another queue based on the selector expression mentioned below.
At the same time I need to make sure that the I am not missing any records in `processMessage` channel. Assuming that the below configuration is good to go? 
or is there any better way to handle this situtaion:

```
  <int:recipient-list-router id="router" input-channel="incomingMsg">
           <int:recipient channel="publishToQueue" selector-expression="payload.contains('test trade') "/>
           <int:recipient channel="processMessage"/>
  </int:recipient-list-router>

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10" />
    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="publishToQueue" task-executor="executor"/>
```

The logical explanation is :

```
 IF payload.contains(test trade)
 THEN
    PublishToQueue
 END IF
 ProcessMessage
```

Comment: So what is the question? Is it not working as you expect? What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: sorry if it is not clear to you..my question was whether the above configuration is correct or not? why asked this question is that I don't want to filter any messages being passed to ProcessMessage because of the selector in the other channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is correct and it is really a classical sample for the Recipient List Router. You send message to the `processMessage` unconditionally and the same message is sent to the `publishToQueue` if it fits to the selector expression.

Another way to reach the same is possible via Publish-Subscribe Channel and a Filter in the beginning of the second flow. But I would say your way with the Recipient List Router is really good.

Otherwise it isn't clear what is your question and why you are in doubt to go ahead.

Comment: Thanks Artem. This is what I wanted to confirm. We are getting the real-time messages and I don't want to loose any messages being processed in ProcessMessage channel because of the selector expression in the previous channel.